# BigQuery: An alternative to temporary table to execute this query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, temp-tables

Could you please suggest an **alternative way** to execute the following query (without using Temporary Table as indicated in the image in the below link)?

The question to be answered by the query is:

Find the station (start_station_id) at which the bike (bikeid) with the longest-used bike (longest trip duration) leaves most often.

P.S. WITH clause used here in BigQuery, you can use the SELECT INTO or the CREATE TABLE clauses instead.

[Dataset - table]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqAly.jpg

[the query using a temporary table in BigQuery-image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4jBk.png

Regards,
Eyad

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text.

Comment: I just noticed the flag now; I'm a newbie here, and this is my first post; I've already edited the post to include another photo of the dataset for a better picture.

Comment: What is the reason for you not use the `with` clause? Firstly, looking at your code, I am not sure why you are joining both the tables because you are not using any columns from the `longest_used_bike` temp table at all.

Comment: the longest_used_bike  was aliased as (longest) and used in the join clause. 
and the temporary table using (With) found the longest_used_bike which used alter in the query to find the (start_station_id) where it mostly used as a start station.
However, I need an alternative way to use a Temporary table, such as using subqueries maybe.